# How to determine if browser UI events have the same "cause"

Tags: javascript, browser

How could one determine if multiple browser UI events were caused by the same basic UI interaction?

For example, the user clicks and event listeners trigger for the "blur" and "mousedown" events.  Is there any way to determine that both these events were caused by one user click?

Comment: `Event.type` will tell you what you want to know. You can write your own code or use [jQuery](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_type.asp) .

Answer (score 0):

Basically No. You may check whether the `event.target` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) of both events is the same and you may check if the time between the events is less than a threshold, but you can't tell programmatically if this is "the same UI Interaction" as there actually happen a lot of events in a cascade based on a single interaction.